# Creating EC2 Subnet: InvalidSubnet.Range: The CIDR '10.0.0.0/24' is invalid. │status code: 400

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, subnet

I'm having some trouble with a Terraform project. I have my `main.tf` where I am trying to launch an Auto Scaling group that spans two subnets in the default VPC, a security group, and two EC2 instances.

However, I keep getting messages that state my CIDR block is wrong:

> Error: creating EC2 Subnet: InvalidSubnet.Range: The CIDR '10.0.0.0/24' is invalid.status code: 400, request id: 7b19b5a2-ca0f-4a45-b5dd-b5ed101c6acb

I'm not sure how to go about correcting it. The region is us east 1. Here is a portion of my code:

[image]

Comment: What CIDR ranges you have defined for your default VPC?

Comment: Probably, You are selecting the CIDR range outside of VPC CIDR range.

Comment: Please dont post an image for textual information

Answer (score 0):

The **Default VPC** in AWS typically has a CIDR of `172.31.0.0/16`.

You are attempting to create **subnets** that are part of the `10.0.0.0/16` range, which is NOT part of the VPC's CIDR range.

I recommend that you **create a new VPC** rather than using the Default VPC. If you create the VPC with a CIDR of `10.0.0.0/16`, then your subnets will work.